# How can do an ActiveRecord call on two values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hyperlink

I'm writing a rails app, and i have an Article Model. This model has two attributes of `issue_id` and `article_position`

In the show view i'm attempting to make a button that goes to the "next" article in a series. the articles go in order from 1 to whatever.

How can i properly do the following call (Psuedo-code):
`<%= link_to 'Next', @article_url.where(@article.article_posistion = current_article.article_position + 1, @article.issue_id = current_article.issue_id) %>`

I'm pretty stuck as of right now, if i need to be using find, let me know.

thanks!

Comment: What does your url look like? Do you have any named routes?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method on the `Article` model that would do what you want:

```
def next_article
  Article.where(issue_id: issue_id, article_position: article_position + 1)
end
```

Then in your controller you could do:

```
@next_article = @article.next_article
```

And in your view:

```
<%= link_to 'Next', article_path(@next_article) if @next_article %>
```

This should work how you want, assuming you have `article_path` defined as a named route.

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part.  You should be using `article_path` not `articles_path`. I changed the answer above.

Comment: i'm attempting it with the following code `<%= link_to 'Next', show_article_path(@next_article) if @next_article %>` but i get the error of: `